# Calling/applying lambda vs. function call - the syntax in Ruby is different. Why?

Tags: ruby, lambda-calculus, lambda

I am kinda new to Ruby and still trying to understand some of the language design principles. IF I've got it right, the lambda expression call in Ruby must be with square braces, while the "regular" function call is with "regular"/round braces.

Is there a special reason that the syntax is different? Or, in other words, (why) should the caller be aware whether they call a function or apply a lambda expression?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because in Ruby, methods are not lambdas (like, for example, in JavaScript).

Methods always belong to objects, can be inherited (by sub-classing or mixins), can be overwritten in an object's eigenclass and can be given a block (which is a lambda). They have their own scope for variables. Example method definition:

```
a = :some_variable
def some_method
  # do something, but not possible to access local variable a
end

# call with:
some_method
```

However lambdas/procs are plain closures, maybe stored in a variable - nothing else:

```
a = :some_variable
some_lambda = lambda{
  # do something, access local variable a if you want to
}

# call with:
some_lambda[]
```

Ruby combines both approaches with a powerful syntax, for example, passing blocks:

```
def some_method_with_block(a)
  # do something, call given block (which is a lambda) with:
  yield(a) ? 42 : 21
end

# example call:
some_method_with_block(1) do |x|
  x.odd?
end #=> 42
```

Comment: thanks a lot! yep, JavaScript was a counter-example I had in mind! Would be perfect to have an example about blocks, though I do know what you mean, still feel that I might learn a bit more from your answer :)

Comment: Small point, a block is not a lambda in ruby. Lambdas are objects, blocks are executable pieces of ruby code.

Answer (score 35):

Regular Ruby method calls use `()` not curly braces which are for blocks. If you don't like `[]` for calling a lambda, you can always use the `call` method.

Example:

```
>> by_two = lambda { |x| x * 2 } #=> #<Proc:0x0000000101304588@(irb):1>
>> by_two[5] #=> 10
>> by_two.call(5) #=> 10
```

**Edit**

In newer version of Ruby also:

```
>> by_two.(5) #=> 10
```

As to why you can't just do `by_two(5)`, when Ruby sees a bareword it first tries to resolve it as a local variable and if that fails as a method.

Comment: [1] Fixed in my question: 'round braces' instead of 'curly'. My bad. [2] Suppose that `by_two` is resolved as a variable first. Does it mean that the reason is simply technical (tweaking the parser)? Isn't here any kind of really different things that can appear in lambda call vs. function call or something? Isn't the difference somehow reflected on a language design level?

Comment: See J-_-L's answer below for [2].

Answer (score 13):

If you want brackets, you can do

```
by_two = lambda { |x| x * 2 }
by_two.(5) # => 10
```

Note the `.` between `by_two` and `(5)`.